# Better aligner than bowtie2?

Tags: sequence-alignment, sequence-analysis

`Bowtie2` is probably the most widely used aligner because of it's speed. Burrow-wheeler (BW) algorithms (including `bwa`) tend to be faster. However, they have limitations when it comes to aligning very short reads (e.g. gRNA). Also, setting maximum number of mismatches allowed is complicated by the seed length, overlaps and other parameters.

I wonder if there is any better multi-purpose aligner out there. May be with algorithm other that BW. One which allows special cases e.g. allowing shord reads and high number of mismatches.

Comment: How long is "very short"? Bowtie2 is not optimized for <=36bp query sequences; nor most aligners developed in the past 5 years or so. Bowtie1 or bwa-aln will work better.

Comment: @user172818 When you say "not optimized", do you mean using the default settings, or more generally ?

Comment: @bli in general. Aligning 100bp reads is a very different problem from aligning <36bp reads.

Comment: If I have learned one thing working with bioinformatics over the years, that is there is no such thing as a "multi-purpose" or "overall best" tool out there. Different algorithms are good for different types of data. My recommendation would be to arrange your workflow in a modular way and plug in the best aligner for the type of data you are working on, rather than relying on a "best" solution.

Comment: As of 2020-09-09, according to google scholar, the 2012 bowtie2 paper has 21647 citations, the 2009 bwa paper has 25045 citations. It may be true that `bowtie2` is the most widely used aligner, but not probable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bowtie2 is no longer the fastest aligner. [Salmon](http://salmon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [Kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/download) are much faster, but have been designed to optimise RNASeq mapping. Their speed is gained from avoiding a strict base-to-base alignment, but they can output mostly-aligned reads (i.e. position-only, without local alignment) as pseudo-alignments. See [here](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/pseudobam.html) for more details.

Both Kallisto and Salmon can do additional bootstrapping that is interpreted by *sleuth* for improved performance in isoform detection. They can also output counts that are equivalent to read-level counts from other programs, which can then be used by other downstream gene-based differential expression analysis software (e.g. [DESeq2](http://dx.doi.org/10.12688/f1000research.7563.2)). Salmon has additional options that can  correct mappings for sequence-level and GC bias.

[HISAT2](http://ccb.jhu.edu/software/hisat2/index.shtml) is from the same group as Bowtie2, and does the same sort of stuff, but with a few optimisations added on top. In particular, it's much better at working out split reads from RNASeq runs. Like Bowtie2, it will do local alignment of reads.

For quick alignment of long reads, [minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2#map-long-genomic) works well. For high-accuracy alignment (but comparatively slower), [LAST](https://github.com/mcfrith/last-rna/blob/master/last-long-reads.md) works well.

Most bioinformaticians seem to prefer [STAR](https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR/) for things that Bowtie2 was previously used for. I'm not yet convinced it's a better alternative, and currently prefer HISAT2 for high accuracy short-read alignment.

Comment: Seconded for kallisto, it is very good. But currently downstream support is limited to the other tool from the pachter lab for differential gene expression analysis, called sleuth.

Comment: One advantage to STAR aligner in Bioinformatics and the reason it is used at my work, is the possibility of reading Chimeric alignments (for detecting e.g. circular RNA through custom coding).

Comment: Salmon and Kallisto aren't really aligners and are only useful for RNA-seq, though they are great and very quick. @NatWH Kallisto can also be used with DESeq2 or edgeR.

Comment: @Jared Andrews at least when I last used it, Kallisto only outputs TPM directly, whereas the normalisation applied by DESeq2 requires unnormalised counts. Are there settings to change the output of Kallisto?

Comment: @NatWH It outputs estimated counts as well. And you can see it mentioned as usable for DESeq2 in the [DESeq2 manual](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/DESeq2/inst/doc/DESeq2.html#tximport). 

From kallisto manual: "abundances.tsv is a plaintext file of the abundance estimates. It does not contains bootstrap estimates. Please use the --plaintext mode to output plaintext abundance estimates. Alternatively, kallisto h5dump can be used to output an HDF5 file to plaintext. The first line contains a header for each column, including estimated counts, TPM, effective length."

Comment: @Jared Andrews, yes it is possible by summing over transcript estimated abundances to produce integer-like counts, but Lior Pachter argues [here](https://www.biostars.org/p/143458/#157303) that this should not be done. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @NatWH Basically the same as the response to his comment. Important to note that those concerns were raised nearly 3 years ago and both salmon and kallisto have been updated several times since then. Regardless, since it's recommended by the DESeq2 authors themselves, I am inclined to trust them - see [their paper on the subject](https://f1000research.com/articles/4-1521/v1). And you don't _have_ to summarize to gene-level counts if you don't want to/don't trust it.

Comment: @Jared Andrews alright. I'll leave my comments up in case any future visitors benefit from the links which have been posted.

Comment: I second what @JaredAndrews said: Salmon and Kallisto are not aligners or direct alternatives to Bowtie. I can't how one would replace the pipeline Bowtie mapping -> macs + bigwig with those, or pretty much anything related with sRNA analysis. A read aligner will output the mapping position of a read, whereas salmon and kallisto will output summarized estimates of gene expression based on the read + transcript properties. Since the OP does not state gene / isoform expression as a use case, I have down-voted this answer because of that paragraph.

Comment: Kallisto *can* output position. What it doesn't do is a careful local alignment (and the question didn't specify whether local alignment was important). I indicated other alternatives where local alignment *is* important.